# Gantry Framework is hiding the wrong menu on mobile in Joomla 3.7. How do i get it to hide the correct one?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.5

The site I'm working on has its main menu in the "Navigation" section in gantry. I have another 2 menus on the page (in the "header" area), though they don't actually link anywhere. They exist as "text separators" that show a module in the dropdown box that shows when the "link" is hovered over (so one is a spyglass that shows the search module in the dropdown).

When i shrink the screen size, gantry eventually causes the menu to disappear an then enables the mobile menu, accessed by the burger button.

The problem is, instead of hiding the actual main menu in the navigation section, it's hiding the first "fake" menu search button in the header section.

I can't see anywhere to set which menu is the one that should be hidden. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been stuck on this since yesterday. Finally caved and post about it on this site then find the answer 20 minutes later, naturally.

I needed to check the box marked "Mobile Target" on the menu i want to be the one to be hidden. I thought this did something else so never tried using it but it seems so obvious now.